# Write file instantly (without line buffering) in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script like this,

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "hello" > a.txt

while [ True ]; do

#do something here, very long and possiblely causing system reboot

done
```

It looks like I can only get a normal a.txt (with "hello" inside) if the execution is ended normally. In the case that the "while loop" is running or a system reboot was triggered during the while loop, there will be a blank a.txt.

By Google searching, it seemed to be a line-bufferring issue as shell turns on line bufferring by default. As there is no "Expect" or "stdbuf" installed on my customized Ubuntu, I tried to replace

```
echo "hello" > a.txt
```

with a Perl/C program, where line buffer is disabled. In Perl, I used "$|" and "fflush" was used in C. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Any feedback is appreciated...

Comment: It sounds more like the write failed, or something else clobbered the file. The file should contain that text at the very moment that the echo command finishes running and the shell closes a.txt.

Comment: I'm not convinced that line buffering is the issue; all else apart, the `echo` command outputs a line and so line buffering would cause that to be written to disk.  It might be a problem with full buffering, but the output should be complete and (apparently) on disk when the `echo` completes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Well, maybe not on disk, but at least in the OS / HD output buffer.  Running `sync` after the `echo` command would ensure that it is actually on disk.

Comment: @cdhowie: Yes - I just added 'apparently' to indicate that nuance (moments before I saw your comment).

Comment: Have you tried adding `ls -l a.txt` immediately after the `echo`?  What size does it give (it should be 6)?  You say 'customized Ubuntu' — could the customization somehow have affected the file system behaviour?  Does using `(echo hello > a.txt)` with the parentheses to force a sub-shell make any difference (it shouldn't)?

Comment: Had tried forcing a sub-shell, didn't make a difference. Actually, I had also tried run "sync" before doing echo. Neither works.Probably I will try to call it again after echo.

Comment: Adding "sync" behind the echo, simply WORKS!!! thanks buddy.

Comment: Allow me to reflect more, if there is more than one place has file writing in the script, should it work if running a endless sync in the background? Like this:

while [ True ]; do
  sync
  sleep 2
done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not exactly true. After the echo the file will be written and visible to other programs. That is guaranteed.

What you might be seeing is that the file is not written to the physical disk at this point. That can happen due to the OS's filesystem buffering. Just because the file has been written to and other programs see it doesn't mean that it's been written out to disk. It could just be in memory.

You can request the OS to flush all buffered writes disk with the "sync" command. Try calling that before triggering the reboot to see if that solves your problem.

> The **sync** utility can be called to ensure that all disk writes have been completed before the processor is halted in a way not suitably done by shutdown(8).

Answer (score 2):

Try if it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello"|awk '{print;fflush()}' > a.txt
sync
while [ True ]; do
#do something here, very long and possiblely causing system reboot
done
```

Comment: Old school UNIX trick: Put two or three calls to sync in there.  :)  Just to be sure.  Seriously though, sync should do it.

Comment: if there is more than one place has file writing in the script, should it work if running a endless sync in the background? Like this: while [ True ]; do sync sleep 2 done